# difference between like and regex operator

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

I'm learning MySQL now. I need your help in understanding the difference between these queries:

```
select id from tab where id like '000';

select id from tab where id regex '000';
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first query uses `like` operator but does not use any wildcards. So it's equivalent to:

```
select id from tab where id = '000';
```

which lists only those `id`'s where `id` is `000`.

The second query uses `regex` operator and it lists rows where `id` has `000` **anywhere** in it.

**Example:** It'll list these `id`'s: `1000`,`2000`,`000`,`0001`

To make your first query behave like the second you'll have to use wild card `%` which matches zero or more characters:

```
select id from tab where id like '%000%';
```

To make your second query behave like the fist you'll have to use start anchor(`^`) and end anchor(`$`):

```
select id from tab where id regex '^000$';
```

Comment: To add to this: There *would* be differences if your queries were `...like '000%'` and `'...like '000_'` and `...regex '000[[:alnum:]]+'` and... you'll get the idea ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you meant the first statement to be:

```
select id from tab where id like '%000%';
```

That means: anything (or nothing), followed by '000', followed by anything (or nothing).

This happens to be just what `id regex '000'` does.

Basically, `LIKE` does very simple wildcard matches, and `REGEX` is capable of very complicated wildcard matches.

In fact, regular expressions (`REGEX`) are so capable that they are [1] a whole study in themselves [2] an easy way to introduce very subtle bugs. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

The **like** operator allows for specifying wildcards using the **%** operator.

If for instance you need to specify all words starting with the character **a**, you can do so by using the value **"a%"**. You could also specify words **ending** with a string of characters. E.g. words ending with **ing** can be specified using **"%ing"**

You could also have parameters specifying columns containing values that contain a certain string. E.g. words that contain the characters **fish** can be specified using the like parameter **"%fish%"**

**Regexp** (I don't think there's a regex operator) on the other hand allows you to specify regular expression in comparing values in a column with a parameter. For instance, if you need to retrieve all records that match a phone number in the format 555-666-7777 you can use the parameter **"[[:digit:]]{3}\-[[:digit:]]{3}\-[[:digit:]]{4}"**

E.g. **SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE phone REGEXP "[[:digit:]]{3}\-[[:digit:]]{3}\-[[:digit:]]{4}"**

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for more information on the **REGEXP** operator.